# Can Chang and Wang's proof of Thue’s Theorem on circular packing be extended into other dimentions?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, packing-and-covering, sphere-packing, circle-packing

The simplicity of Chang and Wang's proof of Thue’s Theorem ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4322v1.pdf) on arxiv) on circular packing took me by surprise. Have similar ideas been found helpful in other dimensions? For example, partition the space into smaller sections and show that density is smaller than some threshold in each?